# Android Studio unable to find adb & can only use skd gphone x86 as AVD

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am unable to launch any AVD other than “sdk gphonex86 arm (mobile)” and when I hover over the AVD I would like to use, it appears as such:

[Not applicable for the main.dart configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkjfy.png)

Flutter Doctor does not appear to note any relevant issues:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.264], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

When I attempt to open the AVD I would like to use via the drop-down, I get this error in the Event Log:

```
Error Opening Emulator
emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature…
```

When I create a new virtual device and then attempt to use it, I get this error:

[Unable to locate adb.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MasFc.png)

However when I attempt open the AVD again, I get this error:

[AVD_Test_Nexus is already running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypQTo.png)

Per other posts on this topic, I have not found that my antivirus software (only Windows Defender) has quarantined the file, and I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Android SDK Platform-Tools several times.

When I attempt to delete the AVD itself, I get an error stating:

[An error occurred while deleting the AVD. See idea.log for details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3cRd.png)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What version of flutter sdk are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.17.4

Comment: I had the same issue today, can you try downloading 1.17.3 version? That resolved the issue for me.Hope you are using android studio.

Comment: I changed my flutter version to 1.17.3 and completely reinstalled Android Studio, I am still having the same issues.

Comment: See if File > invalidate cache & restart works.

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately still having the same issues.